# I'm having a problem loading a css sheet in an ejs file. I specified exactly where the css file is and it is still not working

Tags: html, css, node.js, linker, ejs

[image: So I posted the below picture to show you the structure of my project and the style.css link that isn't linking properly. Note that I also tried the static method with express and it didn't work]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CRUD Application</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/crud_app/asset/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>   
    <!-- Header -->
        <header id="header">
            <nav>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <a href="/" class="nav-brand text-dark">User Management system</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    <!-- /Header -->
```

This is the code that is used and note that I also tried the static method using express. When that didn't work I tried this method. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use inline CSS, although it is a bad practice.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should use express then make folder inside the main folder of the project then name it public
just like this : `/curd/public`

then create `css` folder and move the style sheet folder inside it, it will be like this : `/curd/public/css/style.css`

then go to the app.js file or your entry point file whatever you name it,
then put that code inside it

```
app.use(express.static("public"))
```

then go to the ejs file to load the stylesheet file just like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/style.css">
```